# Custom operator error - cannot pass immutable value

Tags: swift

What I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to understand how custom operators works in swift.

```
enum MyEnum: String {
    case String = "String"

    static func << (lhs: inout String?, rhs: MyEnum) {
        lhs = rhs.rawValue
    }
}

class MyClass {

    var value: String?

}

let myClass: MyClass? = MyClass()

myClass!.value << MyEnum.String

myClass!.value // "String"

myClass?.value << MyEnum.String // error: cannot pass immutable value of type 'String?' as inout argument
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Yes, it works! Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, it's because the of the `assignment` property of the `precedencegroup` for the operator – it needs to be `true` to be used in optional chaining like this.

Comment: Is this possible to declare `=` for custom types?

Comment: No, you cannot overload `=` – that would allow for custom implicit type conversions, which could easily be confusing for both the type checker and people reading your code.

Comment: Don't use an operator for this. It doesn't make the code that much shorter, and it just adds unnecessary confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your custom operator, which is just fine (although, why not just use assignment?)

An `inout` value must be mutable. The type of the expression `myClass?.value` is an immutable `Optional<String>`. This is because of optional chaining, unlike `myClass!.value` which force unwraps `myClass` and then applies the member access.

Comment: Can I some how make it works like `myClass?.value = "some string"`

Comment: @user1841146 No, because you'll have the same problem. You'll need to unwrap `myClass` first.

Comment: @user1841146 Oh yes, my mistake. I must have had a typo when I first tried it in a playground. Assignment is a special case and it doesn't count as a normal operator. So use assignment instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `<<` is semantically a non-mutating operator. As such, its [`precedencegroup`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/precedence-group-declaration) is not defined with the `assignment` property being set to `true`, meaning that the operator doesn't follow the same grouping rules as optional chaining.

Therefore your overload of `<<` cannot be used in conjunction with optional chaining (but even if it could; you shouldn't overload a non-mutating operator with a mutating implementation, that's just confusing).

If you were to overload an operator where `assignment` was set to `true`, your code would work just fine. For example, it would work with `<<=` – though don't actually doing this, as `<<=` already has an established meaning (in-place left bit shift), which you're not conforming with.

If you *really* need an operator here; I would advise you define your own:

```
precedencegroup CustomAssignment {
  assignment: true // Allow the operator to be used with optional chaining.
}

infix operator <~ : CustomAssignment

enum MyEnum : String {
  case string = "String"

  static func <~ (lhs: inout String?, rhs: MyEnum) {
    lhs = rhs.rawValue
  }
}

class MyClass {
  var value: String?
}

let myClass: MyClass? = MyClass()

myClass?.value <~ MyEnum.string
print(myClass?.value as Any) // Optional("String")
```

Personally though, I don't see the value of such an operator over just 
`myClass?.value = MyEnum.string.rawValue`. The latter is *much* clearer with only a few extra characters.

Comment: Thanks for explanations. I'm just trying to understand the capabilities of operators overloading, what we can and what we can not to do. In C++, as I remember, we can do anything with operator overloading, i.e. overload any operator for any type, some times it helpful.

Comment: @user1841146 No worries – Swift is still fairly flexible with operator overloading, but it encourages you not to overload operators that have established meanings with implementations that don't meet them (prime example being not allowing overloads of `=`). In addition, you shouldn't sacrifice clarity for brevity; if there needs to be a type conversion or property access, then making that explicit is generally clearer than burying it under a custom operator.

Comment: Thank you, I'm grateful for your answers!

Comment: Can you give me the link to apple docs about operator overloading? I can not find their link with good explanations.

Comment: @user1841146 Operator overloading (and the exception for `=`) is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID42), `precedencegroup` (as well as custom operator declarations) is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/precedence-group-declaration).